# No notification for comments posted on answers in my questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

I recently opened one of my earlier asked question in hinduism.stackexchange.com and I was surprised to see that there was a big discussion going on in the comments of one of the answers. But here I have not received any notification of these comments. It seems that if I have posted something, eg, a question or an answer and a comment is added on top of only the item posted by me then only I will get notified else I will not.

In my case since the question was asked by me and answer was posted by someone else so all the comments notifications added on the answer would be going only to the one who answered or the people tagged with @ symbol. But since I was the one who asked the question it was initially my doubt, and people discussing or telling good information in comments is something that just goes unnoticed by me because of the site feature.

I request to get this feature corrected such that the person who has asked the question gets notified for all the answers/comments that gets added/edited/deleted with his question/answers.

EDIT: 
This question was said to be duplicate with [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/receive-notifications-for-comments-on-any-answers-to-your-question?rq=1) having the following answer:

> Comments aren't meant to carry significant information - we should instead encourage users to post answers if they have information relevant to the question, or post comments to the question directly if they have comments about the question.

But this does not answer the following situations:

1. Sometimes the comment is based on the the answer. Consider a case i asked a question 'where is xyz written in some religion book', someone answered 'it is written on page 10'. Now I will be only notified about this answer. but assume that after some days, someone puts a comment on this answer saying that 'Page 10 does not describe what is being asked it describes something else'. Now, how will I know that the answer was not correct or is disputed. But if i get the notification for comment. I would have easily known what was correct.
2. Also many a times both the person who has replied and the person who has commented are in a discussion via comments proving their points and contradicting other's points and final outcome can be decided only after reading all the comments. This is a very common in religious stackexchange sites.
3. Also, may be the person who has asked the question also knows something about the discussion which can lead the discussion in a different and correct direction. But here the owner of the question is not given any chance by not notifying him. This is a very basic feature that should be there in stackexchange.

So, please understand that without this feature stack exchange is actually providing wrong/incomplete information to the questioner. You must have read the phrase 'Half information is dangerous', it implies perfectly here. Please remove the duplicate tag and think over the feature request again and please consider having it.

Comment: Not a bug.  You aren't notified by design.  The feature request is a dup of [Receive Notifications for Comments on any Answers to Your Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/receive-notifications-for-comments-on-any-answers-to-your-question?rq=1)

Comment: I have added my views in the comments of the answer in the original question now. Will they be considered for a second thought on the feature request?

Comment: I have updated the question, can the duplicate tag be removed and it can be considered to be looked again.

Comment: Having different arguments to another question, and the answer(s) not answering *your* question, do not stop your question being a dupe. As a good guide, consider: *Can the other (duped) question answer my question?* If yes then the other question is a dupe (most of the time). The other question essentially asks the same basic thing yours does. This being Meta, especially MSE, you can *answer* the other question to provide your arguments, point out why the proposed feature request is a good idea, etc. So answer the other question and provide the missing "points" from your question here :)

Comment: @James I earlier thought that question of tag 'feature request' is a request from a user to MSE & answers comes directly from MSE staff, who decide whether to have a feature or not. But from your comment, it seems anyone can answer. Anyways, my points are extension to the actual question or a contradiction to the answer given there, so I haven't stated that as an answer but as comment to the answer. But if its ok to put as an answer then what will be the next step. I mean, who will see and configure the feature request and how will i know whether any action will be taken on it or not.

Comment: @James, also as the duplicate notice said 'This question has been asked before and already has an answer. IF THOSE ANSWERS DO NOT FULLY ADDRESS YOUR QUESTION, PLEASE EDIT THE QUESTION TO EXPLAIN HOW IT IS DIFFERENT or ask a new question.', so i actually edited my answer accordingly to explain my point. Also, the other question is very old, ie, from year 2010 and I am not sure if anyone would look at it again. I don't see even the questioner further trying to explain after the answer. So, seemed to be kind of closed issue. But no problem, I will put my points there as well in form of answer.

Comment: I agree the on-hold reason could be worded better. If you provide an answer to the other question stating more than "I agree", such as arguments and ideas as to why this would be a good feature etc, then anyone reading the proposal, including staff, will see your answer and thus your arguments for this specific feature/idea. Your answer will also bump the question and get some more views.